# i am trying to compute primes and am having problems with the primeswithin

Tags: java

```
//i have this so far

public class Primes {
    private boolean[] nums;
    private int upperbound;

    public Primes(int n) {

        nums = new boolean[n + 1];
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            nums[i] = true;
    }

    public static final int DEFAULT_UPPER_BOUND = 100 + 1;

    public boolean isPrime(int x) {
        if (nums[x] == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isComposite(int x) {
        if (nums[x] == true) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int getPrimesWithin(int min, int max) {
        for (int n = min; n <= max; n++) {
            if (nums[n] == true) {
                return n;
            }

        }
        return max;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String a = "";
        a += (nums) + " ";
        return a;
    }

    public int getUpperBound() {
        return nums.length;
    }

    public int nthPrime(int n) {
        int count = 0;
        int index = 2;

        while (count < n) {
            if (nums[index] = true) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void computePrimes(int x) {
        for (int i = 2; i * i <= x; i++) {
            if (nums[i]) {
                for (int j = i; i * j <= x; j++) {
                    nums[i * j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void changeUpperBound(int x) {
        upperbound = x;
    }

}

//it needs to fit this

public class Prime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Primes somePrimes = new Primes();
        System.out.println("Default Prime object");
        System.out.println(somePrimes);
        System.out.println("Upper Bound: " + somePrimes.getUpperBound());
        System.out.println("4th prime: " + somePrimes.nthPrime(4));
        System.out.println("7 prime?: " + somePrimes.isPrime(7));
        System.out.println("7 composite?: " + somePrimes.isComposite(7));
        somePrimes.changeUpperBound(50);
        System.out.println(somePrimes);
        int[] primes = somePrimes.getPrimesWithin(40, 50);
        System.out.print("Primes between 40 and 50: ");
        for (int p : primes)
            System.out.print(p + " ");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("*******************");

        Primes myPrimes = new Primes(53);
        System.out.println(myPrimes);
        System.out.println("Upper Bound: " + myPrimes.getUpperBound());
        System.out.println("10th prime: " + myPrimes.nthPrime(10));
        System.out.println("15 prime?: " + myPrimes.isPrime(15));
        System.out.println("15 composite?: " + myPrimes.isComposite(15));
        myPrimes.changeUpperBound(200);
        System.out.println(myPrimes);
        int[] primes2 = myPrimes.getPrimesWithin(50, 97);
        System.out.print("Primes between 50 and 97: ");
        for (int p : primes2)
            System.out.print(p + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// i am not sure how to make the primeswithin work and if you notice any other errors there are probably several
```

Specifications for Primes class:

Instance field:
 private boolean[] nums;  // you can choose another logical name
 // is a variable for the size necessary, or can we just use .length?

Class constant: 
public static final int DEFAULT_UPPER_BOUND = ?;   // choose a value and use in default 
// constructor. If the upper bound (highest number that can be tested for prime) is 10,
// what would be the size of the array?

Accessors:
 boolean isPrime(int x) 
boolean isComposite(int x)
 int nthPrime(int n)      // example:  nthPrime(4) returns 7 because 7 is the 4
th
 prime
 int[] getPrimesWithin(int min, int max)  // returns an array of prime numbers between min and max
 String toString()   // returns a String version of all primes in the data set
 getUpperBound()  // returns the highest number that can be tested for prime (highest index)

Modifiers:
 private void computePrimes() // uses algorithm, called only by each constructor
 void changeUpperBound(int x) // changes the array so that the highest index is x

Constructors:
 Primes(int upperBound)
 Primes() // uses DEFAULT_UPPER_BOUND constant

Output from tester: 
Default Prime object
primes through 100 : 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 
Upper Bound: 100
4th prime: 7
7 prime?: true
7 composite?: false
primes through 50 : 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 
Primes between 40 and 50: 41 43 47

---

primes through 53 : 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 
Upper Bound: 53 
10th prime: 29
15 prime?: false
15 composite?: true
primes through 200 : 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127
131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199 
Primes between 50 and 97: 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97

Comment: In computePrimes, the inner loop should be for (int j = i; j <= x; j += i) { nums[j] = false; }

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of an `int[]` as the return type for `primesWithin`.  Iterate through the big array within the required range, and for each prime that you come to, add it to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: unfortunately one of the restrictions on this assignment is no arraylists but that would work thanks

Comment: OK, do you want to add the restrictions to your question?  Otherwise, people will waste their time coming up with more and more solutions, only to have you tell them that it doesn't fit the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
public int[] getPrimesWithin(int min, int max)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            if(nums[i])
            {
            count++;
            }

        int[] temp = new int[count];
        count = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            if(nums[i])
            {
                temp[count] = i;
                count++;
            }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.